# Probability of sum and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm learning some basics of probability and my background is made solely on the theorical side, that is, measure theory. I know most of the definitions but I'm still learning to calculate some stuff. The exercise that I'm struggling with goes as follows:

> Let $\mathbf{X} = (X,Y)$ be a bivariate random vector with joint probability distribution given by $$\mathbb{P}(X = x, Y = y) = \frac{\lambda^x \mu^y e^{-(\lambda + \mu)}}{x!y!}I_{\mathbb{Z}_+}(x)I_{\mathbb{Z}_+}(y),$$ where $I_{\mathbb{Z}_+}$ is the indicator function on $\mathbb{Z}_+ = \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.
>
> 1. Find the distribution of $X$ conditioned to $X + Y$. Identify the distribution;
> 2. Find $\mathbb{E}(X \mid X + Y)$ and $\mathbb{Var}(X)$.

Now for my attempt to solve it:

For the first item, I understand that I'm expected to find the general formula for $$\mathbb{P}(X = x \mid X + Y = z) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X = x, X + Y = z)}{\mathbb{P}(X + Y = z)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X = x, Y = z - x)}{\mathbb{P}(X + Y = z)}.$$
I know how to find $\mathbb{P}(X = x, Y = z - x)$, so, let's find $\mathbb{P}(X + Y = z)$. We have \begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X + Y = z) &= \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X = k, Y = z - k) \\ &= \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^k \mu^{z - k} e^{-(\lambda + \mu)}}{k!(z - k)!}I_{\mathbb{Z}_+}(k)I_{\mathbb{Z}_+}(z-k) \\ &= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^k \mu^{z - k} e^{-(\lambda + \mu)}}{k!(z - k)!}I_{\mathbb{Z}_+}(z-k) \\ &= \sum_{k = 1}^{z - 1} \frac{\lambda^k \mu^{z - k} e^{-(\lambda + \mu)}}{k!(z - k)!}.
\end{align}

That way, $$\mathbb{P}(X = x, X + Y = z) = \frac{\frac{\lambda^x \mu^{z-x} e^{-(\lambda + \mu)}}{x!(z - x)!}}{\sum_{k = 1}^{z - 1} \frac{\lambda^k \mu^{z - k} e^{-(\lambda + \mu)}}{k!(z - k)!}}I_{\mathbb{Z}_+}(x)I_{\mathbb{Z}_+}(z-x) = \frac{\lambda^x \mu^{z-x}}{x!(z - x)!\sum_{k = 1}^{z - 1} \frac{\lambda^k \mu^{z - k}}{k!(z - k)!}}I_{\mathbb{Z}_+}(x)I_{\mathbb{Z}_+}(z-x).$$

The problem here is that I have no idea how to identify this distribution or if I can simply the expression in a smart way.

For the second item, I know that $\mathbb{E}(X \mid X + Y)$ is a random variable that has the same expectancy of $X$ over every set in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X + Y$, but I have no idea how to find it explicitly. I also don't know if there is an explicit way of calculating $\mathbb{Var}(X)$ from the joint probability distribution.

Comment: By the way, it should be $\mathbb Z_+ = \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$

Comment: @Andrew I don't know the convention, but my inference professor mentioned positive integers, so I assumed he was talking about $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.

Comment: The convention is usually that positive means non-negative, and similarly, $\mathbb Z_+ = \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$, likewise $\mathbb R_+ = [0,\infty)$, likewise $\mathcal S_+ = $positive semi-definite matrices, etc. Moreover, you can check that it is necessarily $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ and not $\mathbb Z_{>0}$, the latter will not give you a probability measure

Comment: @LucasGiraldi  To be a probability mass function, its sum over the support must equal 1.  It will not do so if you are only summing over the positive integers, so the joint support must include the zeroes.$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty\sum_{y=0}^\infty \dfrac{\lambda^x\mu^y\mathrm e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}}{x!~y!}~=~ 1$$

Comment: Oh, right, should've thought about the sum being $1$ over the support. My bad haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $(X,Y) \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)\otimes \mathrm{Pois}(\mu)$. Using generating functions (probability generating functions, moment generating function, or characteristic function all work here), one has $X+Y \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda+\mu)$. Details of such a calculation can be found in Chapter 5 of Grimmett and Stirzaker; proofs that moment generating function and characteristic function uniquely determine probability measures can be found in Billinsgley's Prob. and Measure. The main point is that for any probability measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb R$, the characteristic function (fourier transform) $t\mapsto\int e^{itx}\nu(dx)$ uniquely determines it, and is particularly convenient when working with independent sums.

Thus $$\frac{P(X=x,Y=z-x)}{P(X+Y)=z} = \frac{\lambda^x \mu^{z-x}}{x!(z-x)!}e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}\left\{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}\frac{(\lambda+\mu)^z}{z!}\right\}^{-1} = \binom{z}{x}\frac{\lambda^x\mu^{z-x}}{(\lambda+\mu)^x(\lambda+\mu)^{z-x}}$$
Whence (c.f. the section on regular conditional distribution in Durrett's PTE 5e)
$$X \mid X+Y \sim \mathrm{Bin}(X+Y, \lambda/(\lambda+\mu)) \implies E(X\mid X+Y) = \lambda(X+Y)/(\lambda+\mu)$$
Finally, since $X\sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)$, one has $\mathrm Var(X) = \lambda$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you expand on your calculations using the moment generating functions? I know they exist but I never worked with them. If you don't want to, which is completely fine, can you recommend me a good source where I can find full examples mentioning how to calculate the distribution of a sum using these functions?

Comment: Also, I don't understand the how i could do the "simple calculation" you mentioned when finding the distribution of $X \mid X+Y$. Should I find explicitly the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X+Y$ and then use the expectancy definition?

Comment: @LucasGiraldi edited

Comment: @LucasGiraldi The Probability Generating Function for $X\sim\mathcal{Pois}(\lambda)$ is $$\begin{align}\mathsf G_X(t) &:=\mathsf E(t^X)\\&=\sum_{x\in\Bbb N}\left[(\lambda t)^x\mathrm e^{-\lambda}\middle/x!\right]\\&= \mathrm e^{\lambda(t-1)}\end{align}$$Show that since $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $\mathsf G_{X+Y}(t) = \mathrm e^{(\lambda+\mu)(t-1)}$ and hence $\mathsf P(X+Y=z)=\left.(\lambda+\mu)^z\mathrm e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}\middle/z!\right.$ .